# Best way to implement search view with google map, model and observable

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, viewmodel, searchview

Well, it looks like something simple but haven't found any answer at the moment. I have a search view in my app and i want to add search feature on google map markers. My question is what is the best way to achieve this considering the following code implementation.

My activity is mapped with an observable to retrieve data from db, then i display markers on a map when i get data. A textview is showing count.
This is my main fragment with the google map. As you can see i use observable to update ui.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
....
private void observerSetup() {
        homeViewModel.getCount().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer s) {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(s));
            }
        });

        homeViewModel.getAll().observe(this, new Observer<List<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Items> itemsLoaded) {
                    if(itemsLoaded != null){
                        // build markers
                        buildMarkersFromItems(itemsLoaded);
                    }
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

All is working fine. Now i have to add a search feature with a search view, so i put this.

```
   /**
     * ********************* SEARCH ********************
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText != null && newText.length() > 0){
                if(googleMap != null && markersList.size() > 0){
                    Marker lastMarkerFound = null;
                    for(Marker marker  : markersList) {
                        Item item = (Item) marker.getTag();
                        boolean found = StringUtils.search(item.getName(), newText);
                        marker.setVisible(found);
                    }
                }
            }
            // display all markers
            else{
                for(Marker marker  : markersList){
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
      });
    }
```

The final step is to implements the filter's feature in the view model and UI but i don't know to achieve this. I have to hide/show markers regarding the search filter and update the counter text field. Or should i do some stuff in my fragment ?
But how, what is the best way ?

Here is my model. It use a repository to retrieve data from my db.

```
public class HomeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;
    private Repository mRepository;

    public HomeViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mRepository = new Repository(application);
    }

    public void filter(String text){
      // how to perform something here to update ?
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getCount() {
        return mRepository.count();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Item>> getAll() { return mRepository.getAll();
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit : i posted my solution, not sure it is the best but working. Just tell me if you have any advice.